# Ionic List Angular side by side

Tags: html, angularjs, list, ionic-framework

So, i am creating an Ionic app, and i want to generate side by side list items, or divs, that are generated from a .json file.

HTML:

```
<ion-list class="section" show-reorder="data.showReorder">

        <ion-item ng-class="{'thumb':item.thumb}" ng-repeat='item in muscles | filter:query'
         href="#/tab/muscles/{{item.shortname}}">
          <div class="item item-divider">
            <h2> <b>{{item.name}}</b> </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="item item-thumbnail">
            <img ng-src="img/{{item.shortname}}_tn.png" alt=" {{item.name}} Photo">
          </div>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

CSS:

```
.section ion-item{
position: relative;
float: left;

width:50%;
height:200px;
}

.section ion-item img{
width:75%;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

The current issue is that the Ion-items are doing what they need to do (taking up 50% of the page, side by side) but the Header & Image are not filling that ion-item.  They are taking up maybe a 60% squre inside, and are cut off slightly

Comment: copy the code twice into two separate block of div such as <div class="row" ng-repeat="array in obj2">
        
    </div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="array in obj2">
        <div ng-repeat="object in array">{{object}}</div>
    </div>

Comment: do you have a Plunker that could demo that?

Comment: @jahirul Islam Bhuiyan.  I added in my actual code, can you take a look?

Comment: what you want to put right side of the screen?

Comment: The image & the h2 tags do not completely fill the div.item's.  Ive been trying to look online for previous issues like this.  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2080

Comment: try following css --.section ion-item{
width:100%;
}
.section ion-item item-divider{
width:50%;
height:200px;
}

.section ion-item item-thumbnail{
float: left;
width:45%;
}
.section ion-item img{
width:75%;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;
}

Comment: Ill give it a try when i get home, and let you know if it works out.  Previously i wasnt able to make the css do the trick, but ill see if i can mess with what you added here.  Thanks